How can I put node at center (left or right) of a tikzpicture automatically?
I am trying to make Calendar for 2025. I tried
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar}
\newcommand{\printmonth}[2]{
  \begin{minipage}{0.3\linewidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node at (1.5, 1.5) {\Large \textbf{#1}}; 
      \calendar[
        dates=2025-#2-01 to 2025-#2-last,
        at={(0, 0)},
        week list,
        if={(Sunday) [red, font=\bfseries]}
             ]
      ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \vspace{.5cm}
  \end{minipage}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \Huge \textbf{Calendar for 2025}
\end{center}
\begin{paracol}{3} 
\printmonth{January}{01} \switchcolumn
\printmonth{February}{02} \switchcolumn
\printmonth{March}{03} \switchcolumn*
\printmonth{April}{04} \switchcolumn
\printmonth{May}{05} \switchcolumn
\printmonth{June}{06} \switchcolumn*
\printmonth{July}{07} \switchcolumn
\printmonth{August}{08} \switchcolumn
\printmonth{September}{09} \switchcolumn*
\printmonth{October}{10} \switchcolumn
\printmonth{ November}{11} \switchcolumn
\printmonth{December}{12} \switchcolumn*
\end{paracol}
\end{document}


I use \node at (1.5, 1.5) {\Large \textbf{#1}}; by hand. How can I align (left, center or right) automatically?

Instead of manually adding the name, let the calendar add the month name for you. It has predefined styles for month label above centered, month label above left, month label above right, etc.:
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar}
\newcommand{\printmonth}[2]{
  \begin{minipage}{0.3\linewidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \calendar[
        dates=2025-#2-01 to 2025-#2-last,
        at={(0, 0)},
        week list,
        if={(Sunday) [red, font=\bfseries]},
%        month label above left,
        month label above centered,
%        month label above right,
        month text={\Large\textbf{#1}},
        every month/.append style={yshift=0.5cm}
             ]
      ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \vspace{.5cm}
  \end{minipage}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \Huge \textbf{Celenda for 2025}
\end{center}
\begin{paracol}{3} 
\printmonth{January}{01} \switchcolumn
\printmonth{February}{02} \switchcolumn
\printmonth{March}{03} \switchcolumn*
\printmonth{April}{04} \switchcolumn
\printmonth{May}{05} \switchcolumn
\printmonth{June}{06} \switchcolumn*
\printmonth{July}{07} \switchcolumn
\printmonth{August}{08} \switchcolumn
\printmonth{September}{09} \switchcolumn*
\printmonth{October}{10} \switchcolumn
\printmonth{ November}{11} \switchcolumn
\printmonth{December}{12} \switchcolumn*
\end{paracol}
\end{document}



Notet that with paracol you can lose the minipages and just use \centering once.

@JohnKormylo Thank you very much.
